# Submenu Dynamic Width

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

i'm trying to create a Dynamic Sub-menu to use it in Wordpress, Something like this: http://picbox.im/image/2b5fb80c74-preview.jpg but there is a Width Problem, the width is 'auto' but it is not floating the sub-menu, it is a list, I want they with float:left , but it is not happening, what should a do?

Here is this: http://jsfiddle.net/hD7Ay/1/

There is another problem: The List-style isn't working right.

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Make them all in one line, Use that rule in the SubMenu Ul : `white-space: nowrap;`

Example Here: http://jsfiddle.net/hD7Ay/3/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: awesome! I learned something too :), anyways if you still want to know how to do it via jquery, here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3tsnN/4/, the only difference is that you're actually centering your submenu.

Comment: Hehe, thanks a lot again Paradise, That Question was hard, For me is Hard to use Js yet, but, 'living and Learning'! Now the only problem is to set the Left of the Sub-menu to 1/3 of his width, But i Believe that is Imposible, so, I used that for -250px, works fine! Thanks a lot again Paradise!

Comment: yeah when it comes to css is annoying that you can't do simple math operations in your stylesheet .___. I know that feeling haha, that's when jquery comes to the rescue! BTW no problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok lemme know if this is what you were trying to achieve, your question kinda lacked of design  meaning.

http://jsfiddle.net/3tsnN/

Comment: Almost that, I Want the Submenu Itens Floated Left, not in a list, understand? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: oh ok well the only work around for this is to make it via jquery or js, because width:auto will work with it's parent width, in this case

Comment: Hmm, Oh Hell, I was trying to avoid it. Thanks for that. Do you know how to do it in a simple way? Thanks a lot again, it was very useful.

Comment: well via css you could use selectors look at this example, I'm using simple math, calculating how much width each sub menu should have by it's options, your parent in this case the main option before submenu has a 90px width so I multiply the first one x4 and the second one x5 and then I just rest it's half with the propertie of "left" so its centered to the main option on the menu http://jsfiddle.net/3tsnN/2/ by selectors I meant :nth-child(N)

Comment: but for this in order to work you specifically have to know how many subsections each main option is going to have, i'm telling you this cuz i know you will use it in wordpress

Comment: Hmm, Ok. But there isn't a Way to use Javascript to calcule each sub-menu iten width, add with the other's width and use that number to be the Ul width? Cuz it need to be very dynamic. Thanks a lot again for the help!